# Configure iptables on remote server without locking me up

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a little remote server that I can access only with SSH, and what I want to do, is block all the traffic except port 22 for SSH.

The first time, what I did was :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

And of course, it locked me up because I didn't let any input traffic, so I couldn't add the following rules to accept SSH traffic.

How can I block all the traffic (except SSH) and in the same time letting me have access to the server through SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first set this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

It will authorize already open connection to continue then accept ssh connection (here by ethernet port)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

Finally you can drop every connections

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

#### edit

You should also allow the `loopback` to do anything

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Ok ! Thanks for your answer, I'll try out, it would to the trick :)

Comment: Hum, if I understand well, iptables read rules from top to bottom.
If I add : `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT` before `iptables -P INPUT DROP` will iptables drop all coming traffic at the end ?

Comment: No because you have a difference between rules and policy. Policy are general behaviour the last applyed and rules are apply in order