# Safely configuring `iptables` on a remote system?

Tags: networking, iptables, remote

I want to configure a complex IP-tables configuration on a system that is only accessible via ethernet.

What are the best practices for recovering from the inevitable typos? See for example "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124238/configure-iptables-on-remote-server-without-locking-me-up".

Ideally:

- I'd like to have a 1 minute 'recovery' that would automatically remove recent rules.
- However, I couldn't find a quick way to delete line number ranges across both `INPUT` and `NAT` line tables.

Are the `INPUT` rules in the above link sufficient to protect against all iptables mess-ups (eg, with NAT)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a crond script which checks whether there are (new) SSH clients connected. If there are none, disable `iptables`. Once you're content with your rules, disable the script.

---

In response to your comment. Create e.g. a script with this content:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Call it `disable-iptables.sh`, make it executable with `chmod a+x disable-iptables.sh` and run it, `./disable-iptables.sh`

Comment: If you could suggest a one-linear to "disable iptables" then I could just do. `(sleep 120; <disable iptables here>)& pid=$!'  and manually  'kill $pid'  without cron.

Comment: @HaltState that's what this offers you. Put it in a script, as suggested, and call it from `at 'now +10 minutes'` (or whatever the actual syntax is - can't test just now). You can use `atrm ...` to remove the job, and then resubmit it each time you get to a successful milestone point